# Python - how to multiply only certain numbers in 2 lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

Say I have 2 list:

```
list1 = np.array([1,4,2,5])
list2 = np.array([2,3,4,5])
```

I have been multiplying those to get

```
[2,12,8,25]
```

What if I only want to multiply the ones that are smaller than 3 in list1?
So I will get
`[2,8]` only

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
[i*j for i,j in zip(list1,list2) if i < 3]
```

After the `zip(list1,list2)` you can add a condition. If that condition is not met, that specific item will be skipped. Hence, you can add the restriction you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
In [3]: list1[list1<3] * list2[list1<3]
Out[3]: array([2, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a mask where your values in `list1` meet your condition and then use this to mask your array and perform the multiplication:

```
In [315]:

list1 = np.array([1,4,2,5])
list2 = np.array([2,3,4,5])
mask = np.where(list1 < 3)
list1[mask] * list2[mask]
Out[315]:
array([2, 8])
```